# ORA-00934: "Group funtion is not allowed here"

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am relatively new to SQL and databases in general, can you please explain what am I doing wrong here? I am trying to implement a database for Netflix in my assignment.
This is my schema for the details table:

[image]

I want to list all the latest movies. Content_ID is a number assigned to each movie/show in content table. I wrote my query like this:

[image]

Could you please explain what should be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.  What does "movie" have to do with the data you are showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the Group function with where clause.

You want to filter the rows before grouping use where predicate and if you want to filter out groups created by group by clause then use Having clause.

```
SELECT CONTENT_ID
FROM DETAILS
WHERE DATE_ADDED = ( SELECT MAX(DATE_ADDED) FROM DETAILS)
GROUP BY CONTEN_ID
```

Where clause simply restricts the rows fetched from table using predicate and it does not work on a group of rows that's why you are getting this error.

```
ORA - 00934: group function is not allowed here.
```

But if you want aggregated data in your predicate then use subquery like

```
WHERE date_added = ( scalar subquery returning single row of date_added)
```

or

```
WHERE date_added IN (multiple-row subquery return date_added)
```

And if you want to filter out groups after using group by clause then
using Having.

```
SELECT department_id, MAX(salary) FROM employees 
GROUP BY department_id 
HAVING MAX(salary) > 5000;
```